# Chrome 86: TypeError: Accessor properties are not allowed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, accessor

I defined a property accessor that used to work before the Chrome `Version 86.0.4240.80 (Official Build) (x86_64)` update.

```
const newSetItem = (x, y) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(`custom_${x}`, y)
}

Object.defineProperty(localStorage, 'setItem', {get: newSetItem, configurable: true, writeable: true})
```

Also, this is currently working fine in Firefox and Edge and `Chrome 85`.

Now it throws:

```
TypeError: Accessor properties are not allowed.
```

Is this a feature or something is wrong in the latest Chrome version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to turn a standard method (`setItem`) of a host-provided exotic object (`localStorage`) into a accessor property setter method. Even if it worked, it would be a tremendously bad idea. (Also note that setter methods only accept a **single** parameter, not two.)

**If** your goal is make setting something in `localStorage` set it in `sessionStorage` instead, the simplest way would be to make the `localStorage` global point to `sessionStorage` instead. You can't assign to it (it's read-only), but you can reconfigure it:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", {
    value: sessionStorage,
    configurable: true
});
```

*(Simply `let localStorage = sessionStorage;` would also work if you could be sure there wasn't any code using `window.localStorage.setItem(...)` instead of just `localStorage.setItem(...)` but you probably can't make that assumption.)*

I am ***not*** recommending doing that, though. I'd do anything I could to change the requirement of writing to `localStorage` writing to `sessionStorage` instead. But if you can't, then that's how you'd do it.

If you didn't want to make them equivalent like that, then you'd have to do the same sort of thing to replace `localStorage` with a Proxy object. The reason it has to be a Proxy is that `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` don't only provide access to items through `setItem` and `getItem`, they also provide named access as properties (e.g., `localStorage.foo = "bar";`). The only way to emulate wildcard accessor properties in JavaScript is to use a Proxy object that provides handlers for the the `get` and `set`/`defineProperty` traps.